# How to split csv file in fixed number of columns in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

Hi I have csv file having 622 columns. I need to split it into 100-100 columns. I have tried some code but didn't get output. Please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Example:

file - cleanBaby.csv

In output I want:

```
cleanBaby1.csv ---- 1 to 100 columns
cleanBaby2.csv ---- 101 to 200 
cleanBaby3,csv ---- 201 to 300
cleanBaby4.csv ---- 301 to 400
cleanBaby5.csv ---- 401 to 500
cleanBaby6.csv ---- 501 to 600
cleanBaby7.csv ---- 601 to 622
```

I tried below code-

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\Users\SPate233\Downloads\iMedical\raw_layer\cleanBaby.csv", delimiter=',')
lst = df.columns

print(len(lst))
csvfile = open(r'D:\Users\SPate233\Downloads\iMedical\raw_layer\cleanBaby.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8').readlines()
def chunks(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

for n, headers_chunk in enumerate(chunks(lst, 100)):
    with open(r"D:\Users\SPate233\Downloads\iMedical\raw_layer\cleanBaby{}.csv".format(n), "w") as f:
        for header in headers_chunk:
            f.write(header + ",")
            f.writelines(csvfile[n+100:n])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` with `enumerate`:

```
# Sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((500, 622)))

# Make grouper
indices = np.arange(df.shape[1])//100

for n, (k, d) in enumerate(df.groupby(indices, axis=1), 1):
    name = "test%s.csv" % n
    print(name, d.shape)
    d.to_csv(name, index=False)
```

Output:

```
test1.csv (500, 100)
test2.csv (500, 100)
test3.csv (500, 100)
test4.csv (500, 100)
test5.csv (500, 100)
test6.csv (500, 100)
test7.csv (500, 22)
```

Comment: in every file before first column extra ',' is coming.

Comment: @ShivikaPatel Yes. By default it's `True` and will save the index to the file as well. I've edited my answer